# How to add the sliders values in Bokeh for python

Tags: python, maps, geospatial, bokeh

I am not able to figure it how to add the income bar in the sliders and what does circle mean inside. Can anyone help me solving this. I am now able add title on the top of slider. I have attached link the reference below. This is what I have [Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWMfG.jpg) .

Needed this type [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uYA3.jpg)

```
necessary imports
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.tile_providers import CARTODBPOSITRON
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import math
from ast import literal_eval
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis5
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource,ColorBar,BasicTicker
from bokeh.models.mappers import ColorMapper, LinearColorMapper

#function to convert latitude and longitude into mercator projection mapping
def merc(Coords):
    Coordinates = literal_eval(Coords)
    lat = Coordinates[0]
    lon = Coordinates[1]
    r_major = 6378137.000
    x = r_major * math.radians(lon)
    scale = x/lon
    y = 180.0/math.pi * math.log(math.tan(math.pi/4.0 + lat * (math.pi/180.0)/2.0)) * scale
    return (x, y)

#supporting function
def make_tuple_str(x, y):
    t = (x, y)
    return str(t)

#read with pandas
df = pd.read_csv('housing.csv')

#converting latitude and longitudes of corners of california into mercator range
range0 = merc('(32.080577, -114.052642)')
range1 = merc('(42.356802, -124.753326)')
x_range = (range0[0],range1[0])
y_range = (range0[1], range1[1])

#now convert DataFrame longitude and latitude column into mercator coordinates
df['coords'] = df.apply(lambda x: make_tuple_str(x['latitude'], x['longitude']), axis = 1)
df['coords_latitude'] = df['coords'].apply(lambda x: merc(x)[0])
df['coords_longitude'] = df['coords'].apply(lambda x: merc(x)[1])

#prepare data
source = ColumnDataSource(
    data = dict(
        lat = df['coords_latitude'].tolist(),
        lon = df['coords_longitude'].tolist(),
        size = df.median_income.tolist(),
        color = df.median_house_value.tolist()
        )
    )

#initiate figure
p = figure(x_range = x_range, y_range = y_range, x_axis_type = "mercator", y_axis_type = "mercator")
p.add_tile(CARTODBPOSITRON)

#color palette
color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = Viridis5)

#add a glyph
p.circle(x = 'lat', y = 'lon', 
        size = 'size',
        color = {'field':'color',
                 'transform':color_mapper},
        source = source 
        )
#put a colorbar to support
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, ticker=BasicTicker(),
                     label_standoff=12, border_line_color=None, location=(0,0))

#layout
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')

#show it in web browser
output_file('example.html')

show(p)
```

The link to the main code is :

https://zapcircle.net/geomapping-with-python/

Comment: It's not clear at all what you are trying to accompish. A Slider is GUI widget but there is not one in your code, or any of your screenshots. It's also not clear what "what does circle mean inside" refers to. What circle, inside what?

Comment: I need to write what values does the slider carry